# Multiple API Calls : Design Patterns

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have to call several services having multiple API's. Few of them are basically read(they return me some data) and few of them change the state of several objects(they basically update the state of the several objects).

I am looking for a `design pattern` which can be applied to the above scenario.

**Code Example**

Lets take a small example of a service A

```
AccountInfo A.getAccountInfo() 
void A.setAccountData(AccountInfo) 
AccountStatus A.getStatusForAccount
```

...

I thought of having a Generic Interface

```
interface CallAPI<Input , Output> {
   public Output execute(Input)
}
```

Each API call would implement this interface and I can use Factory pattern to get instances of the API's.

I would like to know if there is a better pattern for the same or it can be refactored in a different way. The APIs and services would only increase and it should be easier to set up new APIs and the clients should not have additional overhead to writing adapters for new APIs.

Comment: take a look on Retrofit it's have a similar way to what you try to acheive

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to start with solid design agnostic from databases, infraestructure details, etc. The way to go is with FactoryMethod and if want to create a family of objects use abstract factory so you can have SqlFamily objects, JsonFamily objects, etc. Then you can create business rules son you can use multiple service, do somtehing more interesting. Agood design implies using multiple desing patterns, so an option also would in addition to factories, using template methos for code reusing, also strategy pattern, etc. Here is the code where you can identify different desing patterns discuss above in place:

```
public interface IRead<T>
{
    T Fetch();
}

public abstract class ServiceA
{
    public abstract void OperationA();
    public abstract void OperationB();
}

public abstract class ServiceB
{
    public abstract void OperationD();
    public abstract void OperationE();
}

public abstract class JsonServiceAReaderTemplate : IRead<ServiceA>
{
    public abstract ServiceA Fetch();
}

public sealed class JsonServiceAFetcher : JsonServiceAReaderTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get parameters needded to load from json
    /// </summary>
    public JsonServiceAFetcher()
    {

    }
    public override ServiceA Fetch()
    {
        //Load from Json store
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public abstract class JsonServiceBReaderTemplate : IRead<ServiceB>
{
    public abstract ServiceB Fetch();
}

public sealed class JsonServiceBFetcher : JsonServiceBReaderTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get parameters needded to load from json
    /// </summary>
    public JsonServiceBFetcher()
    {

    }
    public override ServiceB Fetch()
    {
        //Load from Json store
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class ServicesGateway
{
    public ServiceA ServiceA { get; }
    public ServiceB ServiceB { get; }

    public ServicesGateway(IRead<ServiceA> serviceA, IRead<ServiceB> serviceB)
    {
        ServiceA = serviceA.Fetch();
        ServiceB = serviceB.Fetch();
    }
}

public interface IBusinessRule
{
    void Execute();
}

public sealed class BusinessRuleServiceAServiceB : IBusinessRule
{
    private readonly ServicesGateway servicesGateway;

    public BusinessRuleServiceAServiceB(ServicesGateway servicesGateway)
    {
        this.servicesGateway = servicesGateway;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var serviceA = servicesGateway.ServiceA;
        var serviceB = servicesGateway.ServiceB;
        serviceA.OperationA();
        serviceA.OperationB();
        serviceB.OperationD();
        serviceB.OperationE();
    }
}

public sealed class ClientCode
{
    public void Run()
    {
        //Inject from IoC
        ServicesGateway gateway = new ServicesGateway(new JsonServiceAFetcher(), new JsonServiceBFetcher());
        var businessRule = new BusinessRuleServiceAServiceB(gateway);
        businessRule.Execute();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!